# Django - How to access elements in list by parent loop counter in template

Tags: python, django, web, django-templates

I have this code

```
{% for time in listOfTimes %}
    {% for booking in someOtherList.forloop.parentloop.counter0 %}
        {{ booking }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The `booking` variable does not get printed. I think this was because I cannot access `someOtherList` by using the `forloop` counter. How would I get the `booking` value?

Comment: You want to access bookings from `someOtherList` by index value of parent loop `listOfTimes`?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You really ought to change your Django View and structure the context so that logic is kept out of the Template. Create a List of Dictionaries with all your relevant time data, or do something to make looping inside a loop trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data is as follows:

```
listOfTimes = ['time1', 'time2']
someOtherList = [['booking1', 'booking2'], ['booking3', 'booking4']]
```

Then in template you can do this:

```
{% for time in listOfTimes %}
    {% for booking in someOtherList|get_index:forloop.counter0 %}
        {{ booking }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Notice the `get_index` filter in above code, you need to write this custom filter in your app `templatetags`:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_index(l, i):
    return l[i]
```

Note: Your two list should be of same size, otherwise an `IndexError` might be raised.